# How do I use a runnable to do work in a Singleton?

Tags: java, multithreading, singleton, runnable

I have a question about using a runnable to do work in a singleton.

I have an EventCoordinator class that is a singleton because it is the one that handles all events (and because my assignment requires me to do so).
Events get added to this coordinator and will be processes later. 
The events have to be processed in a different thread in which run takes events of the queue and processes them. the start method should start a new thread that takes events of the queue using run.

```java
final public class EventCoordinator implements Runnable {

    protected final static EventCoordinator coordinator = new EventCoordinator();
    protected static LinkedList<QueueItem> queue = new LinkedList<QueueItem>();    
    private EventBroker() {
    }

    private class QueueItem {
        protected Event event;


        public QueueItem(Event event) {
            this.event = event;
        }
    }

    public static EventCoordinator getEventCoordinator () {
        return coordinator;
    }

    public void addEventObserver(EventObserver o) {
        //adds listeners to the coordinator
    }



    void addEvent(EventPublisher source, Event e) {
            QueueItem queueItem = new QueueItem(e, source);
            synchronized(this) { queue.add(queueItem); }
    }


    public void run() {
        // Process items from the queue
    }

    public void start() {
        // start a new thread that processes items of the queue
    }

}
```

But the way I understand runnables is that when you create a `thread = new Thread(New EventCoordinator)` you create a new EventCoordinator object and thus are not working on the same queue anymore.
So how can you use a runnable to do this work of the queue? Do I make the queue static? Do I implement methodes to add and remove items from the queue and do I invoke them on the coordinator returned by getEventCoordinator?

Comment: 1) Use a `BlockingQueue`. 3) get rid of all the `synchronized` blocks. 3) You're basically done.

Comment: Why can't you just do `thread = new Thread(coordinator)`?

Comment: @Deb Which answer you chose as Best? Could you find solution?

Comment: Yes the answer by Roman and elaborated by Jackmerius worked best. I now accepted the most detailed one as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to do what Roman said:

```
public static synchronized EventCoordinator getEventCoordinator() {
    if (coordinator == null) {
         coordinator = new EventCoordinator();
    }
    return coordinator;
}
```

That way when you call `getEventCoordinator()`, you're only ever getting that one instance...you don't want to use `thread = new Thread(new EventCoordinator())` because that defeats the purpose of a singleton.

When you call `thread = new Thread(EventCoordinator.getEventCoordinator())` in your `start()` method, it will create the thread using the singleton instance as the `Runnable`. Then just define how you want to process the queue items in your `run()` method of `EventCoordinator`.

With that being said, the "preferred" approach to a singleton (according to Effective Java by Joshua Bloch) is to use an enum with a single element. If you keep it how it is, you should at least make your `coordinator` field `private` with a `public` accessor method like Roman provided.

Comment: You're right, I was just reiterating what Roman said, but I should've paid closer attention...I updated my answer to include `synchronized`.

Answer (score 1):

try to go by next way (simple singelton implementation):

```
public static EventCoordinator getEventCoordinator () {
    if (coordinator == null) {
         coordinator = new EventCoordinator();
    }
    return coordinator;
}
```

and

```
thread = new Thread(EventCoordinator.getEventCoordinator())
```

Comment: Im new to multithreading, is the different between `thread = new Thread(EventCoordinator.getEventCoordinator())` and `thread = new Thread(new EventCoordinator())` that thread uses the same private members instead the ones of new object? And is the work done in the run's invoked by the different threads still fully parallel?

Comment: the second part of your solution worked I think. However the first one is not needed and not even possible as my constructor is made private.

Comment: It is possible to call the private constructor within the `EventCoordinator` class, just not outside of it. This allows you to create the singleton instance within the class itself, but prevents other instances from being created in other classes.

Answer (score 0):

You could start anonymous thread from start method and In anonymous thread's run method you can call event coordinator's run method that will actually process queue.  If you remove runnable interface of event coordinator you won't have to call run method of event coordinator and queue processing can be done directly in anonymous thread's run method.  There might be a case where processing or removing elements from queue and adding elements in queue happening at the same time.  You will have to handle concurrency there using either synchronized block or some lock.